# Cronjob running but no crontab for user?

Tags: linux, cron

I'm having troubles with my crontable on the scientific cluster I'm using. It's a bit peculiar, since the jobs seem to run (I get regular mails from some updates) but when I type

```
crontab -l
```

the response is:

```
>     no crontab for USER
```

Same story for

```
crontab -e
```

where I end up with an unedited file, somewhere in the tmp folder. So my question is: Where could this crontab possibly be? I checked some "standard" places, but it seems that there is nothing.

Any ideas, anybody?

Best,
L.

Comment: /etc/crontab, /etc/cron.d, /etc/cron.daily, etc

Comment: `sudo crontab -l`

Comment: I checked all those places @BobanP.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: I'm not in the sudoers list.

Comment: The contrab is probably run as root. Either you ask to be joined to the sudo list, or you have the root login.

Comment: `ls -l /var/spool/cron`

Comment: Someone else's cron job could be emailing you

Comment: if you are a member of some application admin group (or your sysadmin thinks you are) you might be added to a list of cron email recipients list. And, more than likely a cron job run as root is emailing these to you. I am basing this on the daily cron job emails I receive from servers, I hardly ever logged in, let alone setting up a crontab. Although it is a common industry practice.

Comment: I actually wrote an email script myself and just run this script periodically (didn't know there was an integrated email thing). @BobanP.: I looked in there - no success..

Comment: Then you shoudl analyze mail headers, look at the Received headers, and you will definatly find out where did mail come from.

Comment: The job is presumably set up on some other machine in the cluster. @BobanP. You should write that up as an answer, I think that's as good as it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is good possibility that mails are coming from somewhere else, so you need to make sure where did it come from. Inspect mail headers, particularly `Received:` headers. It will show you that info.

Comment: That helped as a first step, I found that some backup-server kicked in. I wrote an email to the IT guys, since I can't log in this server. Maybe this will do it. Thanks a lot ;)